# Extrapolate in log scale on y axis

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, extrapolation

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] y = [0.07, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.005, 0.002, 0.0007]
```

I want to find what x is when y= 0.000001 and I tried below but it gives me a wrong value.

```
10^(interp1(log10(y),x,10^-6, 'linear','extrap'))
```

Also, would linear extrapolation be possible if I only had two points like so,

```
x = [6,7] y = [0.002, 0.0007]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interp1`'s `linear-extrap` function simply extends the last (or first) segment in the piecewise linear fit made from the points. It doesn't actually create a least-squares fit. This is very evident in the image below:

[image]

How did I get this image? I fixed the following problems with your code:
You are interpolating `log10(y)` vs `x`.

- So the third argument for `interp1` needs to be `log10(new_y)`. For `new_y = 10^-6`, you actually need to pass `-6`.
- The call to `interp1()` will give you `new_x`. You're raising `10` to the result of `interp1`, which is wrong.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
y = [0.07, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.005, 0.002, 0.0007]

logy = log10(y);

plot(logy, x, '-x');

new_y = 10^-6;
new_x = interp1(logy, x, log10(new_y), 'linear', 'extrap')

plot(log10([new_y, y(end)]), [new_x, x(end)], '--r');

plot(log10(new_y), new_x, 'or');
xlabel('log10(y)'); ylabel('x');
```

The short answer to your second question is *yes!*.

Longer answer: replace `x` and `y` in my code above and see if it works<sup>(spoiler: it does)</sup>.
[image]

<sup>Note: I ran this code in [Octave Online](https://octave-online.net/) because I don't have a local MATLAB installation. Shouldn't make a difference to the answer though.</sup>